# BigQuery cost for a project

Tags: google-bigquery

How to find out BigQuery cost for a project programmatically. Is there an API to do that?
Also, is it possible to know the user level cost details for queries made?

Answer (score 1):

To track individual costs for a BigQuery project, you can redirect all logs back to BigQuery - and then you can run queries over these logs.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs

These logs include who ran the query, and how much data was scanned.

---

Another way is using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table, check this post:

- https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/monitor-query-costs/

Comment: Can I get project-level cost programmatically (not project Bigquery level), I can see this link https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery where it says it has to be exported to bigquery or google cloud bucket and download the report, which is fine. But can I programmatically, enable export billing data to bigquery or google cloud bucket somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest)

For example

```
[GET] https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectsId}/billingInfo
```